# sql server 2005 management error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an application that use the DBMS Sql server 2008 express. I use to manage my databases the Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio express 2005.

I create new Database and i'd lik to add to it new table but an error like inthe picture appears:

[image: error]

I have also these services that only the first is starting
[image: services]

Why this error appear? and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be the following links might be of help, give it a try

http://harshgupta71.blogspot.in/2013/02/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found.html

or

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic416551-324-2.aspx#bm1438999